# change value of multi-dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, canvas, multidimensional-array, onclick

I want to change a value of a multi-dimensional array, but this code keeps telling me 
"cannot set property '5' (which is the length of the array I guess) of undefined"

```
obj.figures = new Array(
new Array(6,5,5,5,6,5,5),
new Array(5,0,0,0,5,0,0),
new Array(5,5,5,5,5,5,5),
new Array(0,1,1,1,0,2,2),
new Array(0,1,0,1,0,2,0)
);

function change() {
for(var y = 0; y<obj.figures.length; y++) {
    for(var x = 0; x<obj.figures[y].length; x++) {
        $(y+","+x).addEventListener("click", function() {
            console.log(this.id);
            obj.figures[y][x] = 5;
            }, false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please also share your HTML. What is $(y+","+x) trying to refer to in DOM?

Comment: I am much more confused of binding an event to jQuery object with `addEventListener`. Also the values of `y` and `x` won't be as expected, when event will get fired. Moreover, what are you binding click to? `$("5,4")` won't select anything.

Answer (score 0):

You have to switch your y and x value in this statement:

```
obj.figures[y][x] = 5;
```

Should be

```
obj.figures[x][y] = 5;
```

Comment: i found out what the problem was,

    `function change() {
    for(var y = 0; y<obj.figures.length; y++) {
        for(var x = 0; x<obj.figures[y].length; x++) {
            $(y+","+x).addEventListener("click", function() {
                console.log(this.id);
                obj.change = this.id.split(",");
                obj.figures[obj.change[0]][obj.change[1]] = 5;
                }, false);
            }
        }
    }`